# "Must" and "cannot" with "be going to"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, modal-verbs, semi-modals

My father and I have been discussing whether it is possible to concatenate the semi-modal verb "**be going to**" with modal verbs "**must**" or "**cannot**". In our opinion, which we both agreed on, this combination is likely possible:

1. *She **must be going to** tell him the truth.* - meaning "*There is a high probabily that she is going to tell him the truth*"
2. *He **can't be going to** skip classes today.* - meaning "*I don't believe that he is going to skip classes today*"

What do you native speakers think of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I have trouble reading "be going to" as semi-modal in those sentences, and a cursory Google search seems to confirm my suspicions that for most native speakers, it cannot be semi-modal in that context either.

My initial reading of:

> She must be going to tell him the truth.

is that "She must be going *to where he is* to tell him the truth". There is a similar assumption with your second example that the *going* is an actual action, and that "he" must be physically going to school/university (or any other place with classes).

That said, certain American native speakers allow double modals, and I would not be surprised if your examples are considered colloquial or "bad grammar" by them, but nonetheless something they'd use informally. See [Yale's page on multiple modals](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/multiple-modals) for a formal analysis and examples:

> I don't think I have any grants you *might could* apply for.

In this case, the *might could* is roughly equivalent to *might be able to*. Your examples would then mean what you expected them to mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I intend to tell her the truth, I can say:

> I am going to tell her the truth.

No change of physical location is intended there. It is a future.

But locomotion might be implied by the same structure:

> I am going to feed the parking meter.

I could mean there that I'm leaving to put money in the meter.

The two verb phrases would have slightly different intonations.

> I'm going to téll her the truth.
>
> I'm góing to feed the parking meter.

*Must be going to VERB* expresses a predicted future.

> He must be going to tell her the truth.

sounds like someone predicting, with some degree of certainty based on evidence, what a character in a soap opera, say, intends to do.

These are perfectly legit mainstream constructions, not considered regional or substandard in any way.  They're not like "might could".   **can|must|could|should|might|may be going** are not double modals.